# How do I remove gap between multiple window status in tmux status bar?

Tags: tmux

I would like to remove the gaps between the multiple window status in tmux status bar

[image: status bar]

but I have no idea how, here is my setup

```bsh
## current window and pane indices at bottom left corner
set-window-option -g window-status-current-format "\
#[fg=colour239, bg=colour202, bold] #I, #P \
#[fg=colour239, bg=colour214, bold] #W \
#[fg=colour214, bg=colour237]"

## other windows and panes indices at bottom left corner
set-window-option -g window-status-format "\
#[fg=colour239, bg=colour117] #I, #P \
#[fg=colour239, bg=colour118] #W \
#[fg=colour239, bg=colour237]"
```

Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Also please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
set-window-option -g window-status-separator ''
```

> `window-status-separator string`
>   Sets the separator drawn between windows in the status line. The default is a single space character.

<sup>([source](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#window-status-separator))</sup>